# Standard COM marshaler fails with REGDB_E_IIDNOTREG

Tags: winapi, com, typelib

I'm trying to marshal an interface to another thread.

Windows provides the convenient [`CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693316%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) helper function to take care of the boilerplate code associated with using [`CoMarshalInterface`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678428(v=vs.85).aspx) directly.

```
const Guid CLSID_Widget = "{F8383852-FCD3-11d1-A6B9-006097DF5BD4}";
const Guid IID_IWidget  = "{EBBC7C04-315E-11D2-B62F-006097DF5BD4}";

//Create our widget
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Widget, null, 
      CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER | CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, 
      IID_IWidget, out widget);
OleCheck(hr);

//Marshall the interface into an IStream
IStream stm;
hr = CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream(IID_IWidget, widget, out stm);
OleCheck(hr);
```

Except that the call to `CoMarshalThreadInterfaceInStream` fails with:

```
REGDB_E_IIDNOTREG (0x80040155)
Interface not registered
```

### Go directly to CoMarshalInterface

The COM API function **CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream** provides a simple wrapper around `CreateStreamOnHGlobal` and `CoMarshalInterface`, [as shown here](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Essential_COM.html?id=kfRWvKSePmAC&redir_esc=y):

```
// from OLE32.DLL (approx.)
HRESULT CoMarsha1InterThreadInterfaceInStream(
   REFIID riid, IUnknown *pItf, IStream **ppStm) 
{
   HRESULT hr = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(0, TRUE, ppStm);
   if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
       hr = CoMarshalInterface(*ppStm, riid, pItf,
             MSHCTX_INPROC, 0, MSHLFLAGS_NORMAL);
       return hr;
}
```

So we can try ourselves.

```
IStream stm = new Stream()
hr = CoMarshallInterface(stm, IID_IWidget, widget, 
      MSHCTX_INPROC,    // destination context is in-process/same host
      NULL,             // reserved, must be null
      MSHLFLAGS_NORMAL  // marshal once, unmarshal once
);
OleCheck(hr);
```

But that fails with:

```
REGDB_E_IIDNOTREG (0x80040155)
Interface not registered
```

### Use standard marshaling

My class does **not** implement `IMarhsal` interface. This is right and normal.

> By default, when `CoMarshalInterface` is first called on an object, the object is asked whether it wishes to handle its own cross-apartment communications. This question comes in the form of a `QueryInterface` request for the `IMarshal` interface. Most objects do not implement the `IMarshal` interface and fail this
>   `QueryInterface` request, indicating that they are perfectly happy to let COM
>   handle all communications via ORPC calls. Objects that do implement the
>   `IMarshal` interface are indicating that ORPC is inappropriate and that the object implementor would prefer to handle all cross-apartment communications
>   via a custom proxy. When an object implements the `IMarshal`interface all references to the object will be custom marshaled.
>
> When an object does not implement the `IMarshal` interface, all references to the object will be standard marshaled. Most objects elect to use standard marshaling.

So the the question becomes why is the standard COM marshaler having so much problems? What is the source of the error **Interface not registered**?

### The interface is, in fact, not registered

The requires for COM are undocumented, but i can tell you that my interface GUID does **not** exist in:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{EBBC7C04-315E-11D2-B62F-006097DF5BD4}
```

The reason for this will be explained at the end.

I know that Windows provides you the [`CoRegisterPSClsid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function that allows you to register an interface inside your process, so that the standard marshaler will be able to marshal it:

> Enables a downloaded DLL to register its custom interfaces within its running process so that the marshaling code will be able to marshal those interfaces.
>
> ```
> HRESULT CoRegisterPSClsid(
>    _In_ REFIID   riid,
>    _In_ REFCLSID rclsid
> );
> ```

Parameters:

- **`riid`** [in]: A pointer to the IID of the interface to be registered.
- **`rclsid`** [in]: A pointer to the CLSID of the DLL that contains the proxy/stub code for the custom interface specified by riid.

Which i can try calling, but what **clsid** do i use?

```
CoRegisterPSClsid(IID_IWidget, ???);
```

What is the CLSID of the DLL that contains the proxy/stub code for the custom interface specified by riid? Do i use my class itself?

```
CoRegisterPSClsid(IID_IWidget, CLSID_Widget);
```

That doesn't **sound** right; but i don't understand the COM standard marshaler well enough. Doesn't that CLSID have to be one of the standard COM marsharling classes; implementing `IPSFactoryBuffer`?

Either way, it doesn't work. I still get the error "Interface not registered".

### Register the interface

I of course can register my interface in the registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Interface\{EBBC7C04-315E-11D2-B62F-006097DF5BD4}
      (default) = "IWidget"
```

But that doesn't fix it. Spelunking through the `Interface` registry keys, i notice that many specify a **ProxyStubClsid32** entry.

> When a new interface is requested on an object, the proxy and stub managers
>   must resolve the requested IID onto the CLSID of the interface marshaler.
>   Under Windows NT 5.0, the class store maintains these mappings in the NT
>   directory, and they are cached at each host machine in the local registry. The
>   machine-wide IID-to-CLSID mappings are cached at
>
> ```
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface
> ```
>
> and the per-user mappings are cached at
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Interface
> ```
>
> One or both of these keys will contain a subkey for each known interface. If the interface has an interface marshaler installed, there will be an additional
>   subkey (ProxyStubClsid32) that indicates the CLSID of the interface
>   marshaler.

Except what class implements marshaling? I don't have a marshaler.

### Can COM automatically marshal based on a TypeLibrary

Is it possible that if i register a Type Library with my Interface, that COM's standard marshaler will be able to bootstrap a proxy class on the fly?

I registered my interface above. Now i manually include the TypeLibrary:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Interface\{EBBC7C04-315E-11D2-B62F-006097DF5BD4}\TypeLib
      (default) = "{38D528BD-4948-4F28-8E5E-141A51090580}"
```

And if i monitor the registry during the call to `CoMarshalInterface` i see that it attempts, and does find, my Interface IID:

- **Operation:** `RegOpenKey`
- **Path:** `HKCR\WOW6432Node\Interface\{EBBC7C04-315E-11D2-B62F-006097DF5BD4}`
- **Result:** `SUCCESS`

It then tries to look for a **ProxyStubClsid32**, and fails:

- **Operation:** `RegOpenKey`
- **Path:** `HKCR\WOW6432Node\Interface\{668790E3-83CC-47E0-907F-A44BA9A99C8D}\ProxyStubClsid32`
- **Result:** `NAME NOT FOUND`

My **hope** would then be that the standard COM marshaler attempts to look for:

- **Operation:** `RegOpenKey`
- **Path:** `HKCR\WOW6432Node\Interface\{668790E3-83CC-47E0-907F-A44BA9A99C8D}\TypeLib`

But it doesn't.

### The OLE Automation marshaler

According to Don Box, the **Ole Automation** marshaler (PSOAInterface - {00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}) is able to build a stub/proxy out of a type library:

> **The Type Library Marshaler**
>
> When these specially annotated interfaces are encountered by **RegisterTypeLib** (or LoadTypeLib in legacy mode), COM adds `ProxyStubClsid32` entries for the interface with the value `{00020424-0000-0000-C0000-000000000046}`. This GUID corresponds to the class **PSOAInterface** that is registered as living in OLEAUT32.DLL, the OLE automation DLL. Because of the DLL that it lives in, this marshaler is sometimes called the `[oleautomation]` marshaler, although it is also called the type library marshaler or the universal marshaler. I'll refer to it as the type library marshaler, since it really has very little to do with IDispatch. (In fact, it is common to use the `[oleautomation]` attribute on interfaces that don't derive from IDispatch directly or indirectly.)
>
> The class factory for the type library marshaler does something very tricky in its **CreateProxy** and **CreateStub** routines. Rather than return a statically compiled vtable (which is impossible given the fact that the requested interface didn't exist when OLEAUT32.DLL was built as part of the OS), the type library marshaler actually builds an /Oicf-style proxy and stub based on the type library for the interface. Because there is no efficient way to find the `ITypeInfo` for an arbitrary interface, the **LIBID** and **version** of the interface's type library must be stored under the:
>
> ```
> HKCR\Interface\{XXX}\TypeLib
> ```
>
> registry key.

I tried to set `PSOAInterface` as my interface's ProxyStub class:

- Register standard COM class PSOAInterface as our proxy stub clsid

  ```
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Interface\{EBBC7C04-315E-11D2-B62F-006097DF5BD4}\ProxyStubClsid32
         (default) = "{00020424-0000-0000-C0000-000000000046}"
  ```
- Register our type library for our interface

  ```
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Interface\{EBBC7C04-315E-11D2-B62F-006097DF5BD4}\TypeLib
         (default) = "{38D528BD-4948-4F28-8E5E-141A51090580}"
         Version   = "1.0"
  ```
- The type library itself is already registered:

  ```
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TypeLib\{38D528BD-4948-4F28-8E5E-141A51090580}\1.0\0\win32
         (default) = "D:\Junk\ComLibraryProxyTest\Win32\Project1.dll"
  ```

But it still fails.

- it reads `HKCR\Interface\[IID_IWidget]`
- it reads `HKCR\Interface\[IID_IWidget]\ProxyStubClsid32`

But it:

- never reads: `HKCR\Interface\[IID_IWidget]\TypeLib`

So it fails to proxy the object.

## Questions

- Is it **possible** for the standard COM *"Ole Automation"* marshaler to build a proxy class out of a Type Library at runtime?
- Is it possible for **me** to build a proxy class out of a Type Library at runtime?

### Background

`CoMarshalInterface` takes an interface pointer on input and writes the
serialized representation of the pointer to a caller-provided byte stream. This byte stream can then be passed to another apartment, where the
`CoUnmarshalInterface` API function uses the byte stream to return an interface
pointer that is semantically equivalent to the original object yet can be
legally accessed in the apartment that executes the `CoUnmarshalInterface`
call. When calling `CoMarshalInterface`, the caller must indicate how far away
the importing apartment is expected to be. COM defines an enumeration for
expressing this distance:

```
enum MSHCTX {
    MSHCTX_INPROC = 4,           // in-process/same host
    MSHCTX_LOCAL = 0,            // out-of-process/same host
    MSHCTX_NOSHAREDMEM = 1,      //16/32 bit/same host
    MSHCTX_DIFFERENTMACHINE = 2, // off-host
};
```

It is legal to specify a greater distance than required, but it is more efficient
to use the correct MSHCTX when possible. `CoMarshalInterface` also allows
the caller to specify the marshaling semantics using the following marshal flags:

```
enum MSHLFLAGS {
    MSHLFLAGS_NORMAL,      // marshal once, unmarshal once
    MSHLFLAGS_TABLESTRONG, // marshal once, unmarshal many
    MSHLFLAGS_TABLEWEAK,   // marshal once, unmarshal many
    MSHLFlAGS_NOPING = 4   // suppress dist. garbage collection
```

Normal marshaling (sometimes called call marshaling) indicates that the
marshaled object reference must be unmarshaled only once, and if additional
proxies are needed, additional calls to `CoMarshalInterface` are required. Table
marshaling indicates that the marshaled object reference may be unmarshaled
zero or more times without requiring additional calls to CoMarshalInterface.

I think that all COM object type libraries, when compiled by MIDL, can automatically create a proxy/stub factory. But in my case:

> if the COM standard marshaler can't find a proxy/stub factory for an interface, it returns the error REGDB_E_IIDNOTREG.

It may be the case that i have to either:

- use CreateProxyFromTypeInfo and CreateStubFromTypeInfo to create my own proxy
- let the standard COM marshaler automatically create a proxy/stub if there's a typeinfo chunk associated with the interface GUID.

### Bonus Reading

- [Old New Thing: What are the rules for CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream and CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151021-00/?p=91311)
- [Old New Thing: Why do I get the error REGDB_E_IIDNOTREG when I call a method that returns an interface?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090122-00/?p=19413/)
- [Old New Thing: Why do I get E_NOINTERFACE when creating an object that supports that interface?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041213-00/?p=37043)
- [Don Box - MSJ: Standard Marshalling in COM](https://www.microsoft.com/msj/0199/com/com0199.aspx) ([archive](http://archive.is/rNdix))
- [Mysterious disappearing acts by samples from Microsoft SDKs](http://archive.is/4t0Fi)

Comment: Do you still a have a question here? You can use "standard' marshaler if your interface is defined in a typelib which is registered, and the interface is "oleautomation". Is it? You did not mention. Otherwise, you might be able to use PS implementation generated automatically by IDL complier. Next option is to simply implement `IMarshal`. For starters, what sort of interface IWidget is in first place? Does it have a type library? Do you have, or can you generate a Proxy/Stub project for this type library (alike PS project created for standard ATL DLL project in Visual Studio).

Comment: "*I'm trying to marshal an interface to another thread*" - then why go through all these hoops, instead of just using [`IGlobalInterfaceTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678517.aspx) instead?

Comment: Also just in case you want to marshal your interface without actually creating a proxy/stub pair, as a raw pointer that is, you might want to create a free threaded marshaler as aggregated object and expose it's `IMarshal` from your object. If this applies of course (the question touches a lot but not this part).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Because IGlobalInterfaceTable.GetInterfaceFromGlobal fails with a catastrophic failure (E_UNEXPECTED). Which makes sense; GlobalInterfaceTable is a wrapper around CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream, which is a wrapper around CoMarshalInterface, which fails.

Comment: For what it's worth, CoRegisterPSClsid does expect the CLSID parameter to correspond to an implementation of IPSFactoryBuffer. And it should work, but it's some work to do.I'm not sure what's you exact question BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `CoMarshalInterface` actually needs is `IMarshal` implementation (pointer) for the given interface, so that API could request the marshaling magic from it and, in particular, request `IMarshal::GetUnmarshalClass` in order to obtain information who is going to do the reverse magic afterwards:

> [This method is called indirectly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688645), in a call to CoMarshalInterface, by whatever code in the server process is responsible for marshaling a pointer to an interface on an object. This marshaling code is usually a stub generated by COM for one of several interfaces that can marshal a pointer to an interface implemented on an entirely different object.

You don't have `IMarshal` implemented on your widget, so you are going to get it somewhere from.

As you started your question mentioning that you "want to marshal an interface to another thread" and the code comment says "Create our widget" there is a chance that you can utilize `IMarhsal` implementation of [free threaded marshaler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694500). The question does not provide information to tell whether it is possible and/or acceptable solution.

Back to the challenge of obtaining a marshaler, you are trying to work this around by utilizing a "standard" marshaler by "registering the interface":

> why is the standard COM marshaler having so much problems
>
> [...]
>
> I of course can register my interface in the registry

Well, this is not how things actually work.

Interface registration is not just a registry key that "okay, this IID has its own key in the registry". The purpose of such registration is to point where to look for proxy/stub pair for this interface. Your manual creating of registry entries cannot help here if you don't have a proxy/stub DLL for the interface in question. If you had it, you would just regsvr32 it the usual way to create the registry keys.

So called standard marshaler, your next try, is not supposed to marshal any interface and your `IWidget` in particular. OLE supplies so called "PSOAInterface" marshaler, which is capable of supplying proxy/stub pairs for OLE Automation compatible interfaces. Just for them! The marshaler does not have so much problems, it actually has just one: your `IWidget` is unlikely to be compatible or you would not have the problem in first place.

If your `IWidget` was compatible, had an associated type library, where it was marked as [`[oleautomation]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367129), the type library registration process would have automatically created the registry keys referencing PSOAInterface and supplying `ProxyStubClsid32`. Then marshaling API would have picked PSOAInterface for your widget, it would have picked up the registered type library, load details of the interface, then provided standard proxy/stub pair for it and that's it. Standard marshaler works just within these contraints and not just for any interface pointed to.

That is, your options are:

- implement `IMarshal` on the widget server
- make `IWidget` OLE Automation compatible, with type library, so that type library registration process activates "standard marshaler" PSOAInterface for your interface
- build, if possible and applicable, proxy/stub implementation for your interface automatically generated by MIDL complier (you can check standard ATL DLL project, created from Visual Studio template on how it can be done - it creates additional project with "PS" suffix, for a supplementary proxy/stub DLL)
- implement separately `IMarshal` in a standalone DLL, and register it with the registry and your `IWidget` interface, so that marshaling API would pick it up when it attempts to marshal the interface pointer (I suppose it's the only option here if your `IWidget` is OLE incompatible and you have reasons to not alter the original implementation)
- use free threaded marshaler in the widget server if its restrictions are acceptable

Oh wait, hold on - there is another weird one. If you don't want or cannot afford, or you are reluctant to change the COM server (widget, that is) but you can modify client side code as you like, you can create a thin wrapper that implements two interfaces `IWidget` (all methods forward calls to real server) and `IMarshal` on client side, and pass its `IWidget` to the `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream` API. This will force COM to use your marshaling without altering the original server. You are on your own, of course, to do the actual marshaling afterwards. It is unlikely that it matches your actual need, and it is just an abstract note to the discussion (which mostly consists of attempts to do impossible without details on interface itself and available options on modification of server implementation).

Comment: I'm using the question as a way to understanding COM marshaling across apartments. In reality, i have a STA COM object (which i did not write) that i want to access from a background thread. I was perfectly happy to let COM do the hard work of marshaling for me. But it turns out [this COM object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775248.aspx) a) does not register its interface, b) does not have a type library. I'm left with either the dangerous way (SendMessage myself), or the hard way (implementing `IMarshal` on a wrapper object myself).

Comment: But in my test COM library, marking the class as [OleAutomation] does allow the **PSOAInterface** marshaler to kick in. It's interesting though that it doesn't care about `HKCR\Interface\[IID]\TypeLib`. It never attempts to read it and i was even allowed to delete it. It also should be noted that i am doing this *not* in Visual Studio, but Delphi - another compiler that targets native Win32.

Comment: Note that [oleautomation] has to be applied to interface IDL, not to coclass.

Comment: I misspoke; it's on the `IWidget` interface.

Comment: PSOAInterface could have queried for `IDispatch`, which `[oleautomation]` assumes, then failed earlier than it reached step of further querying of registry. Also, it could be trying to retrieve type library reference from the interface itself not from registry.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Actual questions:

> - Is it **possible** for the standard COM *"Ole Automation"* marshaler to build a proxy class out of a Type Library at runtime?

Short answer: yes.

> - Is it possible for **me** to build a proxy class out of a Type Library at runtime?

Short answer: yes, with the type library marshaler and [`IPSFactoryBuffer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695281(v=vs.85).aspx). Or if you're willing to use the undocumented `CreateProxyFromTypeInfo` and `CreateStubFromTypeInfo`.

I wonder why you'd want to this.

---

This question is riddled with red herrings.

> I'm trying to marshal an interface to another thread.
>
> (...) the call to `CoMarshalThreadInterfaceInStream` fails with:
>
> ```
> REGDB_E_IIDNOTREG (0x80040155)
> Interface not registered
> ```

A useful error code, in this case.

> Go directly to `CoMarshalInterface`
>
> (...) that fails with:
>
> ```
> REGDB_E_IIDNOTREG (0x80040155)
> Interface not registered
> ```

It's not by switching API calls that do essentially the same thing that you could solve your issue.

> Use standard marshaling
>
> My class does not implement `IMarhsal` interface.

Can you confirm it doesn't implement [`INoMarshal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802477(v=vs.85).aspx), [`IStdMarshalInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694324(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`IAgileObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802476(v=vs.85).aspx) either, just to be exhaustive?

> The interface is, in fact, not registered

This was expected.

> I know that Windows provides you the `CoRegisterPSClsid`
>
> (...)
>
> Which i can try calling, but what **clsid** do i use?
>
> ```
> CoRegisterPSClsid(IID_IWidget, ???);
> ```

If you don't have a proxy/stub, why would you go through this?

But to answer this question, a standard marshalers' CLSID is usually the same GUID as [the first IID found in an IDL file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366768(v=vs.85).aspx).

> Register the interface
>
> I of course can register my interface in the registry:
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Interface\{EBBC7C04-315E-11D2-B62F-006097DF5BD4}
>       (default) = "IWidget"
> ```
>
> But that doesn't fix it. Spelunking through the Interface registry keys, i notice that many specify a **ProxyStubClsid32** entry.

You should read the documentation, instead of relying on what other registry entries contain.

> (...) I don't have a marshaler.

This should be the actual problem.  If this object is yours, how do you intend to marshal it?  Please see the bottom section of my answer.

> Can COM automatically marshal based on a TypeLibrary

This is clearly rhetoric.  Why would you think of a type library just now, instead of to begin with?  The rest of your question corroborates.

> Now i manually include the TypeLibrary:
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Interface\{EBBC7C04-315E-11D2-B62F-006097DF5BD4}\TypeLib
>       (default) = "{38D528BD-4948-4F28-8E5E-141A51090580}"
> ```

You mention this twice.

> But it:
>
> - never reads: HKCR\Interface[IID_IWidget]\TypeLib

The type library marshaler has its own cache of interface->type library.  To clear the cache, try recreating the registry entries, logging off and logging on, or ultimately, reboot.

The object may implement [`IProvideClassInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687303(v=vs.85).aspx), I don't know if the type library marshaler actually cares to `QueryInterface` for this to fetch a runtime `ITypeInfo` to work with.

---

These are the main types of marshalers:

- Standard marshalers, which are usually compiled into a DLL from C/C++ source code generated by MIDL (which consists mainly of declarations on how to marshal types)
- The type library marshaler, which can marshal types at runtime based on automation-compatible type information
- The free-threaded marshaler aggregated with `CoCreateFreeThreadedMarshaler`, which avoids marshaling between threads within the same process
- Custom marshalers, which do whatever the developer wants, most commonly to implement marshal-by-value, or a free-threaded marshaler back when `CoCreateFreeThreadedMarshaler` didn't exist

The standard marshalers generated by MIDL consist mainly of declarations on how to marshal types in and out, so the way they work is in the same vein as the type library marshaler.  According to Don Box, the result is very similar.

However, the actual declarations are very different.  The type library marshaler works on type information that is meant to work in VB6 and (excluding certain things, such as user-defined types) scripting languages (mainly VBScript and JScript) and is intended to be consumed by IDEs (e.g. VB6, VBA, Delphi, OleView) and interop code generators (e.g. VC++ `#import`, tlbimp.exe, Delphi's "Import Type Library", Lisp [<sup>1</sup>](https://franz.com/support/documentation/10.1/doc/ole.htm#type-libraries-2) [<sup>2</sup>](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/COM/html/com-74.htm#14843)), etc.

Comment: The real question is there is a COM object that i want to marshal to another apartment - and it's failing; all the rest is research effort. You can test yourself - you already have the COM object registered on your machine. You did not write it, but you want to access it from a background thread. Create it (`CoCreateInstance("{F8383852-FCD3-11d1-A6B9-006097DF5BD4}", null, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER | CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, "{EBBC7C04-315E-11D2-B62F-006097DF5BD4}", out unk);`) and tell me how to marshal it. One feature of COM was that tried to insulate all this from the caller of the object.

Comment: The safest thing to do is to use a marshalable object in between.  Everything else is too brittle.  `CLSID_ProgressDialog` has a ThreadingModel of Both and it's documented to work in the background, probably in a dedicated thread running a window message dispatching loop.  As long as you use it in the same apartment where you created it, it should work without marshaling.

Comment: If you really need to marshal (e.g. some case other than the progress dialog), you can *clone* an interface in IDL, give it another name and IID and implement an object that forwards calls to this interface to the actual unmarshalable object.  Be careful with further non-marshalable interface pointers.  In the case of the progress dialog, I can see an `HINSTANCE` in `SetAnimation`, a `HWND` in `StartProgressDialog` as reasons to not be marshalable, and `ULONGLONG` in `SetProgress64` as further reasons to not be automation compatible.

Comment: In my case, a background thread wants to update its progress to the user. The background thread is given an `IProgressDialog` it can use to use to update the user. The question then becomes **how** to marshall calls and RPC them across apartments. RPC? Pipes? SendMessage? But the question remains the same: i have an interface that i want to marshal to a background thread - the question doesn't stop until i can call the  com object from a background thread.

Comment: You can provide an object that implements `IProgressDialog` which aggregates the free-threaded marshaler and simply forwards calls to the actual `ProgressDialog`, but this is dangerous if the `ProgressDialog` coclass implementation is apartment-bound in any way.  Another way is to provide an object that implements `IMarshal` which handles `IProgressDialog`, forwarding calls to the actual `ProgressDialog` instance in the correct apartment (how this is achieved is left as an exercise; maybe a <strike>cloned</strike> façade interface with marshalable argument types might be the easiest route).